# ocultar javascript elemento nobr

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo esto

```
<tr>
        <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="190px" class="ms-formlabel"><h3 class="ms-standardheader">
        <nobr>Estado</nobr>
</tr>

<tr>
...
...
...
</tr>

<tr>
...
...
...
</tr>

<tr>
...
...
...
</tr>
```

Lo que quiero es que el tr donde la etiqueta `<nobr>` tenga valor "Estado" se oculte el tr por completo

Estoy intentando

```
$("tr[nobr='Estado']").hide();
```

Pero no hace nada

Como filtrar por etiqueta y su valor?

Gracias

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La consulta CSS `tr[nobr='Estado']` significa *dame los elementos `tr` que tengan el atributo `nobr` con el valor `'Estado'`*.

Es decir, estás buscando algo como

```
<tr nobr="Estado"> ... </tr>
```

Lo que debes buscar es elementos `<nobr>` **dentro de** `<tr>` [cuyo texto contenga](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) `"Estado"`:

```
$('tr nobr:contains("Estado")')
```

```js
let nobr=$("tr td nobr:contains('Estado')");
nobr.parent().parent().hide(); // o nobr.closest('tr').hide()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="190px" class="ms-formlabel">
    <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
        <nobr>Estado</nobr>
    </h3>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Me esta ocultando el <nobr> lo que quiero es que me oculte es todo el <tr>

Comment: @PaoloFrigenti con `.parents('tr').hide()` lo tienes

Comment: editado para ocultar el TR

Answer (score 3):

Como complemento a la respuesta de @pablo-lozano, tienes la opción de utilizar `.filter()` para filtrar aquellos elementos que tengan el valor "Estado" (exclusivamente):

```js
$("#tabla").find("tr").find("nobr").filter(function(index) {
    return $(this).text() === "Estado";
  }).closest("tr").hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tabla">
    <tr>
        <td><h3>Otro td</h3></td>
        <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="190px" class="ms-formlabel">
            <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
                <nobr>Estado</nobr>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="190px" class="ms-formlabel">
            <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
                <nobr>Foo</nobr>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="190px" class="ms-formlabel">
            <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
                <nobr>Bar</nobr>
    </tr>

</table>
```

**Edito**

Como dice @loisb en su comenterio puedes utilizar el `parent()` o si no buscar el `closest("tr")` como he puesto ahora.